# Build e compilação. Quais as diferenças e quando usar?

Tags: delphi, compilação, ide

Em algumas IDE's existem 2 opções para gerar um arquivo executável: **compilar** e efetuar um **build**.
As duas geram um novo arquivo **executável** a partir do código fonte, pronto para ser executado.
Qual a diferença entre os 2 processos?
Quando efetuar um build e quando compilar um projeto?

Comment: Cara creio eu que os dois são a mesma coisa.
Qual programa você viu isso?

Comment: Algumas IDEs usam o termo **compile** para descrever a recompilação apenas do que foi alterado e o termo **build** para descrever a recompilação de todo o projeto e eventualmente a reconstrução do pacote de distribuição. Há linguagens onde você tem que primeiro que compilar e depois gerar o executável, e os dois termos podem descrever estes dois passos. Você tem que especificar de qual ambiente está falando.

Comment: Adicionei a tag "Delphi" na sua pergunta pois ela estava inconsistente, podendo atrair respostas que explicam diferenças conceituais entre "build" e "compile" mas que podem acabar não respondendo sua dúvida específica, que não é apenas conceitual mas envolve uma IDE em específico. Apesar das evidências de que seja Delphi, caso não seja, edite sua pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

### Diferença entre compile e build

Em Delphi, as IDEs tratam o **compile** como sendo uma compilação parcial, e o **build** como sendo uma reconstrução total do seu aplicativo ou *package* ou *dll*. Exemplo:

Você alterou alguns arquivos do código fonte e:

**a)** Invocou um **compile** - apenas os arquivos alterados serão recompilados.

**b)** Invocou um **build** - todos os arquivos serão recompilados e as dependências serão validadas e readicionadas no assembly gerado (executável ou *package* ou *dll* ou *ocx* ou...).

### Quando usar um e quando usar outro?

Em Delphi, use **compile** para depurar ou testar imediatamente o código recém alterado - é mais rápido que build. Sempre use **build** antes dos testes finais e antes de distribuir sua biblioteca ou executável a fim de reflitam no seu código as atlerações que tenham sido efetuadas nas dependências, como *packages* (.bpl) ou *units* (.dcu).

Comment: +1, essa é a resposta mais correta de acordo com a documentação da IDE Delphi

Answer (score 0):

Vou roubartilhar uma resposta a uma pergunta semelhante feita no SO. A pergunta era específica sobre Java mas acho que isso vale para outras plataformas e linguagens.

> O processo de construção envolve vários passos necessários para se gerar uma versao "entregável" do seu software. No mundo do Java, isso geralmente inclui:
>
> - Geração de fontes (as vezes).
> - Compilação dos fontes.
> - Compilação dos fontes de teste.
> - Execução dos testes (testes unitários, de integração, etc).
> - Empacotamento (em `jar`, `war`, `ejb-jar`, `ear`).
> - Checagens de "saúde"/performance (Checkstyle, Findbugs, PMD, test coverage, etc).
> - Geração de relatórios.

Eu mudei um pouco a resposta - estou fazendo uma versão que é minha interpretação aqui. Mas o ponto chave é que **compilar** é o processo de transformar texto código fonte em alguma outra forma que o computador pode processar (linguagem de máquina, bytecoce etc.). A compilação em si é apenas uma parte do processo de **construção**, que envolve não apenas a tradução do código mas também a ligação das partes e todos os demais processos necessários para que o código compilado possa ser utilizado.

Fonte: [Building vs. Compiling (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650423/2263584)

Aproveita e dá uma lida no link ao final da resposta do Pascal, sobre integração contínua ;) Quando se usa IC, é comum se falar em *builds instáveis* e *build estáveis*. Pra quem trabalha com isso, a distinção entre compilar e ter um *build* se torna mais clara. Compilar, o código sempre vai compilar que é uma beleza (se não houver erros de sintaxe). Já ter um build estável é outra coisa.

Veja também essa outra resposta: [What is the difference between compile code and executable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2310280/2263584)

> **Compilar** é o ato de transformar código fonte em código objeto (nota minha: nunca vi essa expressão antes, "código objeto").
>   ***Linking*** é o ato de combinar o código compulado e as bibliotecas utilizadas em um executável "cru".
>   ***Building*** é a sequência composta pela compilação e pelo *linking*, e outras possíveis tarefas como a criação de um instalador.

Comment: "Código objeto" em Clipper é (ou era) uma expressão muito comum. Inclusive os arquivos compilados recebiam a extensão `.obj`. Era equivalente ao `.dcu` do Delphi. Como o AP diz que ambos "compilação" e "build" geram um "arquivo executável", é pouco provável que ele esteja falando de Java. Acho mais provável que esteja falando de Delphi. Neste caso, a diferença é compilar só o que foi alterado (compile) ou recompilar tudo validando inclusive as dependências (build). É difícil uma boa resposta antes da manifestação do AP sobre qual é o ambiente em questão.

Comment: -1 Compilação e Build em delphi são diferentes de java, não se aplica nesse caso, pois o compile e build efetuam todas as etapas de construção de um executável (compilação, linkagem e construção), a única diferença é conforme dito pelo @Caffe, compile recompila apenas os arquivos modificadoes e build recompila todos os arquivos.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Esta resposta foi postada antes de **eu** editar a pergunta adicionando a tag Delphi.

Comment: @Caffé Ok, deveria então ser removida, pois não atende mais aos requisitos da pergunta. Pelo histórico de perguntas do usuário é claro que se trata apenas da IDE Delphi

Comment: Apenas para contribuir com a resposta. “Código Objeto” em copiadores é uma representação de um código escrito em linguagem de alto nível que passou por todas as etapas de compilação (analise léxica, analise sintática, analise semântica, geração de código intermediário, otimização de código e geração de código). O código objeto pode ser representado por uma linguagem simbólica(Assembly), linguagem de máquina ou outra representação qualquer. Código objeto é o resultado do processo de compilação.